# pattern matching without echo

Tags: command-line, wildcards

Why are the outputs different?

```
touch a aa bb ccc

echo *
```

a aa bb ccc // I understood, * means matches zero or more

```
*
```

aa bb ccc // I'm confused.

```
echo ?
```

a //OK

```
?
```

a aa bb ccc // confused again.

```
*?
```

aa bb ccc // very confused

```
* *
```

a    aa   aa   bb   bb   ccc  ccc // very very confused

I wonder what's the difference between using echo and not using it.

Answer (score 3):

Each line you write must have a command, usually the first word.

To get something printed, a common command is `echo`.

If the pwd (present working directory) has files `a`, `aa`, `bb`, and `ccc`.
Then, this command will print all files in the directory:

```
 $ echo *
 a aa bb ccc
```

And this command will print all files in the pwd that have one character:

```
$ echo ?
a
```

---

However, if you do not provide a command, the first "word" (most of the time: up to the first white space) will be taken to be the command.

If you only supply the asterisk `*`, the first word that results from the expansion of the asterisk will be used as the command to execute.

If the command `a` does not exist, an error will be printed:

```
$ *
bash: a: command not found
```

If there is a command called `a`, it will be called with the three arguments `aa bb ccc`.

As you provide no more detail, we can only make a wild guess of which command is being executed with the name `a` (it is not a default command). Also we don't know which shell are you using.

But all your examples show that the first `a` is missing:

```
$ *
aa bb ccc              ### missing first `a`.
$ *?
aa bb ccc              ### missing first `a`.
$ * *
a aa aa bb bb ccc ccc  ### missing first `a`.
```

Except for:

```
$ ?
a aa bb ccc
```

Of which is difficult to make any conclusion as we don't know what command is `a`.

Comment: ... possibly something like `function a { \ls $@; }` such that `*` expands to `ls aa bb cc` while `?` expands to just `ls`

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, that's possible. If the OP could execute `type a` and tell us the result we will probably know.